# spark csv output : getting empty quotes instead of blank or space

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I am trying to find a solution to have the empty quotes in the csv file replaced with a blank space with no quotes. I tried below, but i get a 0 instead of a space in the csv file. Can someone lmk how to get a space instead of "" in the final csv file when the value is empty, thanks.

````
                    ```outputDS
                    .write()
                    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .option("header", true)
                    .option("delimiter", "\t")
                    .option("emptyValue", null)
                    .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
                    .csv(fullOutputPath);```
````

Comment: i am using spark 2.4

Comment: Can you please provide your input data? Is the data present as trapped within single quotes ? Then it won't work. You need to use a map function.

Comment: the input data is not within single quotes. But, does the above options  look okay to you otherwise?  I can run the output and check again.

Comment: also, i included the encoding option for just clarity here, but i dont have it in my actual code, is that required to be set?

Comment: this is resolved. option("emptyValue", null) seems to work on a second run.